# Hide Get Parameter using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Here is my page

```
xyz.com?show=page
```

Inside my index.php the code will be like

```
<?php
echo $_GET['show']
?>
```

But i want users to type only `xyz.com/page` and it should automatically append `?show` in url

How can i do this ?

I have .htaccess like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But it removes only the last part of page i.e., .php

How can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `index.php` will be handling all your requests, you need to rewrite them `index.php`. What you're doing now is rewriting them to the current request and adding a `.php` at the end.

This should do what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /index.php?show=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But it won't work if we have the fiels in  sub folders ?

Comment: You will have to update the question with what you want. I can only guess.